# Can I retrieve paper levels from SNMP from a printer?

Tags: php, printing, ip, snmp

I have code that returns toner levels from some of our network printers:

```
?>

        <h1>IP address: <?php echo $printer; ?></h1>

        <h3>Type: <?php if ($printer->isColorPrinter()) echo 'color printer'; elseif ($printer->isMonoPrinter()) echo 'mono printer'; ?></h3>

        <h3>Factory name: <?php echo $printer->getFactoryId(); ?></h3>

        <h3>Vendor: <?php echo $printer->getVendorName(); ?></h3>

        <h3>Serial Number: <?php echo $printer->getSerialNumber(); ?></h3>

        <span style="background: black; color: white;">Black Toner:</span> <?php echo round($printer->getBlackTonerLevel(), 2); ?> %<br />

        <?php if ($printer->isColorPrinter()): ?>
            <span style="background: cyan; color: black;">Cyan Toner:</span> <?php echo round($printer->getCyanTonerLevel(), 2); ?> %<br />
            <span style="background: magenta; color: white;">Magenta Toner:</span> <?php echo round($printer->getMagentaTonerLevel(), 2); ?> %<br />
            <span style="background: yellow; color: black;">Yellow Toner:</span> <?php echo round($printer->getYellowTonerLevel(), 2); ?> %<br />
        <?php endif; ?>

        <br />
        <span>Drum level: <?php echo $printer->getDrumLevel(); ?> %</span><br />
        <span>Count of printed papers: <?php echo $printer->getNumberOfPrintedPapers(); ?></span><br />

        <h3>Cartridges:</h3>

        <span><?php echo $printer->getBlackCatridgeType(); ?></span><br />
        <span><?php echo $printer->getCyanCatridgeType(); ?></span><br />
        <span><?php echo $printer->getMagentaCatridgeType(); ?></span><br />
        <span><?php echo $printer->getYellowCatridgeType(); ?></span><br />

<?php
```

Is there a method/function I can use to get paper levels in trays like I can with the toner? like:

```
getBlackTonerLevel
```

What would the sytax be for tray1  vs tray2 for example?

Comment: Google "snmp printer mib" to find information about the standard MIB objects for printers.

Comment: Take a look at [Printer MIB v2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3805)

Comment: I don't see anything about `tonerLevel` there, so it seems like your library is using vendor extensions, and this is probably also needed for paper level. You'll probably need to check the documentation of that library to see if it has what you want.